# Finding sets that are not groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find the smallest set closed under a binary operation which has an identity and inverses, but is not a group.

I'm assuming then that associativity does not hold, or else the set along with the binary operation would be a group. How do I find such sets?

Comment: Usually you take a (small) finite set, make a table to define the operation.

Comment: Quibble: it is a type error to ask whether a set is a group. The thing that has the property of groupness is a set together with a binary operation, otherwise known as a magma.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Build one by brute force. You clearly can't do it with one element, so how about two? With $e$ as the identity, the operation table would have to be:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}&e&a\\ \hline
e&e&a\\
a&a&e
\end{array}$$

This, unfortunately, gives you a group, so try it with three elements. An easy way to ensure that you have inverses is to make everything its own inverse:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}&e&a&b\\ \hline
e&e&a&b\\
a&a&e&\\
b&b&&e
\end{array}$$

You won't violate associativity in a product involving the identity, so you might try to ensure that $(ab)a\ne a(ba)$. Can you do that?

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, it can't be a one-element set, because the only operation on such a set yields a group.

Let's take a two-element set $\{a,b\}$. One of the elements has to be an identity. Let's choose $a$. So it must be that $a\cdot a=a$ and $b\cdot a=b=a\cdot b$. Now, we need an inverse of $b$, i.e. such an element $x$ that $xb=a=bx.$ If $a=x,$ we have a contradiction. If however $b=x$, we obtain a group. So a two-element set doesn't work either.

Let's take a three-element set $\{a,b,c\}$. We clearly have to put  $a\cdot a=a$, $b\cdot a=b=a\cdot b$ and $c\cdot a=c=a\cdot c.$ Now, we need an inverse for $b$. Like before, it can't be $a$. Then it must be either $b$ or $c$. There is only one group with three elements up to isomorphism, that is $G=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z.$ So if we choose in a different way than it is in this group we should be fine. In $G$, the non-identity elements are inverse to each other. So if we choose $b$ to be the inverse of $b$, we have a chance of doing well. So $b\cdot b=b$. Now we have to choose the inverse of $c$ and fill out the rest of the multiplication table somehow. I'm sure you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

We can find the smallest examples using [Mace4](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/).  You input the axioms "exists an identity element" and "each element has an inverse", and add the "goal" of proving associativity.  Mace4 will find counter-examples.

This can be achieved by the following input:

```
formulas(sos).

e*x=x.
x*e=x.
x*x'=e.
x'*x=e.

end_of_list.

formulas(goals).

x*(y*z)=(x*y)*z.

end_of_list.
```

The output is the following on my computer (I snipped some of the output; there's quite a lot):

```
=== Mace4 starting on domain size 3. ===

============================== MODEL =================================

interpretation( 3, [number=1, seconds=0], [

        function(e, [ 0 ]),

        function(c1, [ 1 ]),

        function(c2, [ 1 ]),

        function(c3, [ 2 ]),

        function('(_), [ 0, 1, 1 ]),

        function(*(_,_), [
                           0, 1, 2,
                           1, 0, 0,
                           2, 0, 0 ])
]).

============================== end of model ==========================
```

The above says:

- an identity is $e=0$,
- associativity is violated by $c_1=1$, $c_2=1$ and $c_3=2$,
- an inversion is given by $0 \mapsto 0$, $1 \mapsto 1$ and $2 \mapsto 1$.

Modifications to the above input can yield interesting results, for example, there are $46$ non-associative binary operations on the set $\{0,1,2\}$ which admit an identity element, and for which each element has at least one inverse.